# ¿Cómo obtener los hechos en prolog?

Tags: prolog

Hola soy nuevo en `prolog` y quiero saber si hay otra forma de obtener todas las relaciones de los hechos en `prolog`, no se si así se diga pero por ejemplo.

```
%hechos

metadatos(presentacion,embebidos).

metadatos(presentacion,catalogo).

metadatos(presentacion,separado).

%consulta

metadatos(presentacion,X).


X = embebidos ;

X = catalogo ;

X = separado.
```

Quiero saber cómo puedo obtener todos los datos de **X** sin poner `";"`.

Gracias y perdón si no me di a explicar bien.

Comment: Aunque findall es muy común, sería bueno que especificaras que programa usas para programar con prolog, pues no todos implementan prolog de Edimburgo

Answer (score 1):

El estándar ISO Prolog define el predicado incorporado [findall/3](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/findall/3) para buscar todas las respuestas de un objetivo de forma determinista. `findall(Template, Goal, Instances)` es verdad si y solo si `Instances` es una lista de valores de la forma `Template` que hace al objetivo `Goal` tener éxito.

En tu ejemplo, puedes lanzar el objetivo `findall(X, metadatos(presentacion,X), L)`, obteniendo la respuesta `L = [embebidos, catalogo, separado]`. Es decir, te da todos los `X` en la lista `L` tal que el objetivo `metadatos(presentacion,X)` es cierto.